# Django: setting inlineformset modelchoicefield query in views

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have been searching all day for a solution to my problem with no luck,

I have been trying to override one of my form's `ModelChoiceField` in views as the data to filter my modelchoice is in the `views`

I have read somewhere that you can use:

```
def somefunction(request):
    form = someform(request.POST)
    form.fields['formfield'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=YourModel.objects.filter(...))
```

But I am using an `inlineformset_factory`

I have tried looping through the fields like this:

```
for item in form1:
        item.fields['formfield'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=YourModel.objects.filter(...))
```

But it raises an error: `[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']`

But I do have `{{ my_formset.management_form }}` and my test app works if I remove the loop part and just render the formset normally

Here is my view:

```
myformset1 = inlineformset_factory(parentmodel, childmodel, form = formset1, extra = 1, can_delete=True)
myformset2 = inlineformset_factory(parentmodel, childmodel2, form = formset2, extra = 1, can_delete=True)

def somefucntion(request):
    form = mymainform(request.POST)
    form1 = myformset1(request.POST, prefix='f1')
    form2 = myformset2(request.POST, prefix='f2')
    for item in form1:
        item.fields['form1field'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=YourModel.objects.filter(...))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
           cde = form.save(commit = False)
            form1 = myformset1(request.POST, prefix='f1', instance = cde)
            form2 = myformset2(request.POST, prefix='f2', instance = cde)
            if form1.is_valid():
                if form2.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    form1.save()
                    form2.save()
    else:
        form = mymainform()
        form1 = myformset1(instance = myparentmodel, prefix='f1')
        form2 = myformset2(instance = myparentmodel, prefix='f2')

    return render(request, 'frontend/apply.html', {'form': form, 'form1':form1, 'form2': form2})
```

Any tips or suggestion would be greatly appreciated, thanks

**EDIT**

I am using [Django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) to generate my formset dynamically

Comment: You'll need to give a bit more context. Where are you using that code?

Comment: I have updated my post, feel free to comment if the post still lacks in detail

Comment: I am using it in my views

Comment: Please show the *full* view. Are you using the same prefix on the initial GET?

Comment: I am using the `prefix` to ensure that they don't step on each
other

Comment: Please, see my edited post